# Cannot apply operator. How would I fix this?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to display a message only when the datetime is before or on todays date.  Here is what I have:

```
var todaysdate = DateTime.Today;

if (acct.maturityDate <= todaysdate )           
{
   maturityText.Visible = true;  
}
```

I get a message saying that  `(acct.maturityDate <= todaysdate )`.

> Cannot apply operator '<=' to operands of type 'string' and 'system.datetime', candidates are bool <=(system.datetime,system.datetime) (in struct datetime).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not convert maturityDate to an actual `DateTime` type?

Comment: Agreed. If you can show us the format for that string, someone could show you how.

Comment: Why is `maturityDate` a string at all? It wants to be a `DateTime`.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. MaturityDate has to be left as is since its used elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says, `maturityData` is a `string` and not a `DateTime` you need to convert it:

```
var todaysdate = DateTime.Today;

if (DateTime.Parse(acct.maturityDate) <= todaysdate ) {
   maturityText.Visible = true;  
}
```

I'm making a direct parse there, you might want to consider `TryParse` or `ParseExact` depending on your needs.

Comment: Why parsing always if you could make it a `DateTime` property in the first place?

Comment: @TimSchmelter But we don't know if he can, I'm answering the OP only. But yes it'd definitely be more efficient.

Comment: Not only more efficient but also safer if it's possible that the culture changes somewehere, sometime. So maybe he still stores `"01/15/2014 10:30AM"` in `maturityDate` but the current culture is `de-DE` (for example). Boom!

Answer (score 2):

This means that the property `acct.maturityDate` is of the type `string` and not the expected type `System.DateTime`. Convert/parse the property to a DateTime and your problem should be solved, or make sure the property is already a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the type of `maturityDate` is a `string`. using `DateTime.Parse()` would allow you to resolve your issues and so will  [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Converting to the correct type will allow you to use the correct operators.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to change `maturityDate` to `DateTime` type, and then you should use `DateTime.Compare` method you can refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If `maturityDate` must be left as-is, you can either use the `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.TryParse`, or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods.

`Parse` will throw an exception if maturity date cannot be parsed.

`TryParse` and `TryParseExact` will not throw exceptions, but will allow you to make a decision based on whether the date is able to be parsed.

`TryParseExact` allows you to parse your date even if it doesn't match a standard DateTime format.  You simply specify the format string, as well as culture and style information, in the method parameters.

Parse Example:

```
var todaysdate = DateTime.Today;

if (DateTime.Parse(acct.maturityDate) <= todaysdate ) {
   maturityText.Visible = true;  
}
```

TryParse Example:

```
var todaysdate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParse(acct.maturityDate, out dt) 
{
    if (dt <= todaysdate)
    {
       maturityText.Visible = true;  
    }
}
```

TryParseExact Example:

```
var todaysdate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime dt;

// use whatever format string matches appropriately
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(acct.maturityDate, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                  , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                  , DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
{
    if (dt <= todaysdate)
    {
       maturityText.Visible = true;  
    }
}
```